# Should individual project access tokens allow access to other repos in GitLab?

Tags: security, git, clone, gitlab

I seem to have [some fundamental problem](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/why-do-individual-project-access-tokens-give-access-to-all-projects/87337/1) in my GitLab instance somewhere or am not understanding the purpose of project access tokens properly. Some context: Am maintaining multiple different projects for multiple different customers containing arbitrary files. Customers should be allowed to either clone or download their own individual repos, but no others and without creating "real" user accounts in the GitLab instance.

This reads like a perfect use-case for [deploy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/) or [project access tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html). Deploy tokens seem to be working as intended: Specially crafted URLs (`https://_token_customer_reader:PASSWD@SERVER/ORG/bin/releases/CUSTOMER-1.git`) can be used by customers with some Git client to clone the repo. Access to other repos using the same token is forbidden according to my tests. Though, deploy tokens don't allow web browser downloads, cloning only.

Project access tokens OTOH do allow downloads using some web browser (`https://SERVER/api/v4/projects/138/repository/archive.zip?private_token=PASSWD&sha=prod`) because one can grant access to the GitLab API for those. BUT: According to my tests with Git clients and browser, ONE token allows access to ALL other repos in my GitLab instance. One simply needs to change the project ID in the URL and possibly the branch name or commit hash, but downloads succeed with arbitrary different content.

I'm somewhat sure that things didn't work that way in the past when I first thought about those approaches, but I might be wrong of course. OTOH, all of the docs for project access tokens speak about individual tokens, things being scoped to some project and the whole concept only makes sense to me when being per project. Additionally, deploy tokens behave as expected when cloning, the only difference compared to project access tokens seems to be that those are less versatile.

**So, how are project access tokens supposed to work regarding permissions to other, unrelated projects?**

Comment: There's a recently opened issue, though I wonder why not a lot of more people recognized it yet. https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/413028